# TERADATA : Eclipse Plugin Not Connecting With LDAP Mechanism

Tags: eclipse, plugins, connection, ldap, teradata

I am trying to use teradata eclipse plugin.
Eclipse Juno , Plugin Ver : 14
 In the connection setup under Data Source Explorer; i choose the "LDAP" mechanism to connect.
 The connection fails with the following error trace : 
 `com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.21] [Error 8017] [SQLState 28000] The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.`
 However, if i connect to the same server using credentials that are not mapped to LDAP i.e. "PASSWORD_PROTECTED" mechanism; connection is successful.
 Request inputs on this. Are there any other specific settings that should be configured ??

Answer (score 1):

Got a suggestion that besides entering the username and passowrd while setting up LDAP connection in eclipse, 
 one must ensure that the password has a escape sequence if it contains a special character. 
Suggested solution worked for me : [Teradata Eclipse Plugin : Error With LDAP Connectivity](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/teradata-studio/teradata-eclipse-plugin-error-with-ldap-connectivity#comment-129432)